# Macbook Air 2015 fan at 7000rpm

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

I have a brand new Macbook Air and since first start fan is pretty loud.
I've tried SMC restart but that didn't helped.
Now I have installed SMC FAN CONTROL and it's showing that fan speed is currently 6945rpm after the restart, and before it was at 7065rmp.

And fan is pretty loud since I press power button on.
Any idea how to fix it and is it even possible to be 7000rpm?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between 6945rpm & 7065rmp might just be the noise in the measurement - these are both basically saying "7000 rpm".

Perhaps one of the thermal sensors isn't attached/set properly (although this would be unusual for a brand new computer), so it always runs at maximum fan speed just to be safe (which might be nominally 7000rpm in your case).

Since it's brand new I'd take it back and ask the Apple Store to check it.

---

Update:

I found out after years that DropBox (along with some other progs) would caused my fans to blaze. 
Perhaps because I was syncing a massive work DBox drive, it was always computing at max power.

I quit DropBox and the fans start to slow down to a reasonable level. Quitting would DropBox drop the CPU temp and fan speed within ~15-30 sec, although quitting other programs (such as MS Office apps, NetFlix in a browser window) sometimes had some effect if DropBox was already closed.  Since I wanted DBox syncing on, and this indicated that the fans were just blazing due to actual CPU usage (not some hardware problem), I would just learn to live with it (or quit DBox when I wanted a quieter computer).

Comment: See if you can find out what the Mac fan speed is - I seem to remember it's somewhere around 7000-10000rpm. If your computer is always showing max speed, then there's something wrong with one of the thermal sensors.  Of course, it is possible you're doing such intensive work that it's actually working that hard - for example, DropBox indexing can use max processor power and this max fan speed.

Comment: where "Mac" should say "max"

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you tried SMC Restart, I would also try [resetting your PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063):

> 1. Turn your computer off
> 2. Turn it back on and wait until you hear the startup sound
> 3. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound.
> 4. Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for a second time.

The timing of the key presses (after the chime but before the computer starts) can be a bit tricky - if you don't hear the chime a second time, it did not work. It usually takes me a couple tries.

I had an older (~2012) Macbook Pro that had the fans constantly running at full blast a couple years back, and that fixed it for me. Your issue may not be the same, but maybe it can be helpful.

It's unusual to see fans running at 7000 RPM, on my computer they max out at 6000 (possibly because of model differences). For comparison, my current Macbook Pro runs with the fans between 2000-3000 RPM almost all the time, according to SMC Fan Control. The only times it hits 6000 is doing intensive work, like rendering a video.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all your solutions, and bunch others I found on internet. Nothing helped so I'm taking macbook for official service. Guess it's something mechanical.